# detect if PDF file is made from images

Tags: bash, shell-script, pdf

I'm trying to pre-process a huge amount of PDF files, many of them not actually text but images in order to move them to a proper location to OCR processing.

The problem is I've tried to detect if PDF is image based prior to OCR but no success so far.
Using "`pdffonts filename`" is supposed the correct approach but image only PDFs got fonts too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pdfimages -list filename.pdf
```

Should do the trick. This gives you a list of images contained in the PDF file.

Comment: That also gives you a list of images where there is text in addition to  there being images, and those are not "image only PDFs" as the OP asked for.

Comment: Another issue is PDF that mixed images and text

Comment: you can try comparing the number of pages with images `pdfimages -list x.pdf | tr -s ' ' | cut -f2 -d ' ' | uniq | grep ^[1-9] | wc -l` to the total number of pages `pdfinfo x.pdf | grep '^Pages' | grep -oe '[0-9]\+'`

A document with an image on each page is pretty sus (I'm trying to guess OCR'd documents, so every page *will* have "text" regardless)

Answer (score 2):

You can install pdftotext and see if it generated more than no output string:

```
for file_name in *.pdf; do
   if [ $(pdftotext "$file_name")"x" == "x" ] ; then mv "$file_name" /to/ocr ; fi
done
```

Under Debian and derivates that utility is in package `poppler-utils`.

Comment: Anthon, even if the PDF is only made of images you get some lines of text from pdftotext

Comment: @user1319342 not in the 20 or so samples that I tried. Your files might not be image only, I know for sure mine are.